# Is there a way to execute a query on SOLR where I have a list of words that need to be in different fields?

Tags: solr

everybody. I'm trying to elaborate a query that complies with the following:
Find a set of words that appear in a group of fields. For example, i want to find the documents that have the words soccer, ball and goalkeeper in one or both fields: 'sport_name' and 'descritpion'.
The problem I'm having is that I need to treat both fields as only one for getting results like:

```
 {  
        "sport_name":"soccer",  
        "description": "...played with a ball... positions are goalkeeper"  
    }
```

I need that the words appear in any field, but all the words need to appear in the "concatenated bigger field".
 Is there a way to do this during query time?
 Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the edismax handler (`defType=edismax`), setting `q.op=AND` (since all the terms has to be present) and using `qf=sport_name description` to tell Solr to search for the given terms in both fields.

You can also use `qf=sport_name^2 description` to say that you want to weigh hits in the `sport_name` field twice as much as hits in the description field. So if there was a sport named something with `ball`, that hit would contribute more to the score than if the same content were present in the `description` field.